# How to (efficiently) insert into a map with a map as value?

Tags: c++, performance, insert, unordered-map

I am writing a C++ program, to read from a big file line by line, and insert each line-info (after some processing) to an unordered_map.

This is the declaration of the unordered_map:

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int> > entries;
```

What I did to insert was (this is in the loop code-block in which I process each line of the text file):

```
unordered_map<int, int> tmp;
tmp[y] = z;
entries[x] = tmp;
```

But this proved to behave badly in performance terms.

I've tried creating a `pair<int, pair<int, int>>` and inserting it using `entries.insert(the_pair)` but I cannot get this to compile (getting: `no matching member function for call to 'insert'`).

**Edit:**
The program *looks like* this:

```
ifstream ifile(path-to-file);
string line;
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int> > entries;
while (getline(ifile, line)) {
    // some processing with line to find (int) x and (int) y 
    if (entries.find(x) == entries.end()) {
        auto iter_and_success = entries.emplace(x, unordered_map<int, int>{});
        auto &tmp_m = iter_and_success.first->second;
        tmp_m[y] = 1;
    }
    else {
        unordered_map<int, int> r = entries[x];
        if (r.count(y) == 0)
            entries[x][y] = (int) r.size() + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is simply move the child `unordered_map` to the parent one:

```
entries[x] = std::move(tmp);
```

This way you will avoid an extra copy of `tmp`.

Another way is to fill up the child map *after* inserting it.

```
 auto iter_and_success = entries.emplace(x, unordered_map<int, int>{});
 auto& tmp = iter_and_success.first->second;
 tmp[y] = z;
```

This way actually, you will append the data to the child map if `x` happens to occur multiple times (if this is unwanted behavior - just check the bool flag and act accordingly).

---

```
ifstream ifile(path-to-file);
string line;
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int> > entries;
while (getline(ifile, line)) {
    // some processing with line to find (int) x and (int) y 

    // This will insert a new map only if x wasn't present
    auto iter_and_success = entries.emplace(x, unordered_map<int, int>{});

    // This will be 1 if a new map was inserted
    auto value_to_insert = static_cast<int>(iter_and_success.first->second.size()) + 1;

    // This will do anything only if y wasn't present in sub-map
    iter_and_success.first->second.emplace(y, value_to_insert);
}
```

Comment: Using the 1st method, doesn't result in a performance increase unfortunately. Isn't there any way to avoid creating the `tmp` unordered_map and just insert a pair? In this case, a `pair<int, pair<int,int>>`?

Comment: @Chris I wonder how you are testing. Well, the second method should be as fast as you can get with the data structure you have. It will basically achieve what you're looking for - no unnecessary allocations/copies/etc. Notice, that the tmp unordered map won't be created in the second case except for the first insertion with key `x` (note `auto& tmp`. It has to be created at least once due to the data structure you defined.

Comment: @Chris It's hard to analyse it further without the information about your access pattern.

Comment: I've updated my OP with how the program looks. The testing occurs simply by using a file of 1000000 lines as input and then printing the info I gathered. I am measuring the elapsed time with `time` function, which I know is simplistic, but this is what I need now.

Comment: @Chris Ok, this clears things up. I'll update my answer. Hint: `unordered_map<int, int> r = entries[x];` creates a copy.

Comment: Yes, in general I think it would be better if I avoided the `[]` in this case, as I read that it might overwrite the already existing value. Is that correct? (Waiting for your updated answer)

Comment: Yes, you've got the logic alright and also the running time dropped by 15"!